# Mysql to PostgreSql Rails 3 heroku app true/false

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Everything works fine until I push to heroku, I gathered that it has to do with diffirent ways mysql and postgres display the boolean values?

I am using **Ruby 1.9.2p318** and **Rails 3.2.2** with **Mysql 5.2.35** on **Max OSX**

Here is the query I am trying to run

```
@special_offers = Wine.find(:all, :include => [:inventories], :conditions => ["inventories.special = ? AND inventories.warehouse_id IN (?)", "true", @wharehouses_array], :order => "inventories.updated_at DESC", :limit => 3)
```

It seems the problem lies with the `inventories.special = ?, "true"`
This works fine on mysql but not when I push to heroku, wich is using postgres

I have tried replacing the "true" with 1 and "1" and "t" and t and true but nothing seems to work?

---

**UPDATE:**
*Heroku log file*

```
2012-04-04T14:06:58+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-04-04 14:06:58] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2012-04-04T14:06:58+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-04-04 14:06:58] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=54181
2012-04-04T14:06:58+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-04-04 14:06:58] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2012-04-04T14:06:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-04-04T14:07:01+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-04-04T14:07:01+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-04-04T14:07:01+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-04-04T14:07:01+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-04T14:07:01+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:54181
2012-04-04T14:07:01+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-04T14:07:01+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 41.119.121.138 at 2012-04-04 14:07:01 +0000
2012-04-04T14:07:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2012-04-04T14:07:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered partials/_display_wines.html.erb (169.1ms)
2012-04-04T14:07:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered partials/_display_wines.html.erb (0.0ms)
2012-04-04T14:07:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered partials/_display_wines.html.erb (8.1ms)
2012-04-04T14:07:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (259.9ms)
2012-04-04T14:07:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered partials/_header_bar.html.erb (6.5ms)
2012-04-04T14:07:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered partials/_main_links.html.erb (0.3ms)
2012-04-04T14:07:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered partials/_footer.html.erb (4.9ms)
2012-04-04T14:07:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 1081ms (Views: 345.8ms | ActiveRecord: 175.7ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
2012-04-04T14:07:03+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=1350ms status=200 bytes=36808
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/javascripts/jquery.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=137ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/stylesheets/style1.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=179ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /stylesheets/style1.css] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /javascripts/jquery.js] miss

+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /javascripts/script1.js] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/javascripts/script1.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=187ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/javascripts/PIE.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=185ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/javascripts/rails.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=189ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /javascripts/PIE.js] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /javascripts/rails.js] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/header_tile.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/header_tile.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=16ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/none.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/none.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=35ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/cybercellar_logo.jpg] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/flags.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/flags.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=96ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/cybercellar_logo.jpg dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=84ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/header_login.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/header_login.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=44ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/no_wine.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/no_wine.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=22ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/buttons2.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/buttons2.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=19ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/find_wine_wrap.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/find_wine_wrap.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=22ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/comment.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/comment.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/bullet.png] miss

4:07:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/bullet.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=13ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/buttons.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/buttons.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/links_bar.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/hr_light.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/hr_light.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/links_bar.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=17ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/cart_background.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/cart_background.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/home_page_image.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/home_page_image.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/find_wine.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/find_wine.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=10ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/footer_tile.jpg] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:05+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/footer_tile.jpg dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:06+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/social.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:06+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/hr_dark.jpg dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:06+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/hr_dark.jpg] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:06+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/social.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:06+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/credit_cards.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:06+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/credit_cards.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=14ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-04-04T14:07:06+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/money_back.png] miss
2012-04-04T14:07:06+00:00 heroku[router]: GET stormy-fog-6888.herokuapp.com/images/money_back.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=0
```

---

**Schema file: for the inventories table**

```
create_table "inventories", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer   "wine_id"
    t.integer   "warehouse_id"
    t.integer   "stock"
    t.float     "price"
    t.integer   "quantity_id"
    t.timestamp "created_at"
    t.timestamp "updated_at"
    t.boolean   "available",                        :default => false
    t.boolean   "discount",                         :default => false
    t.string    "markupprofile_id",   :limit => 45
    t.string    "discountprofile_id", :limit => 45
    t.float     "discount_price"
    t.boolean   "special",                          :default => false
  end
```

Comment: The SQL generated and the error from PostgreSQL would be helpful. Once you've got those, somebody can tell you straight away. Actually , once you've got those you'll probably not need to ask.

Comment: *nothing seems to work* is not a valid error message.

Comment: I had a look at the heroku log file, it does not show any error messages, it just does not query the fields when using `Wine.find(:all, :include => [:inventories], :conditions => ["inventories.special = ? ", "true"])` because the "true" value is not the same in postgresql?

Answer (score 2):

Use the actual TrueClass, not a string, and Rails will translate it into the correct query for you.

Correct:

```
"inventories.special = ?", true
```

Incorrect:

```
"inventories.special = ?", "true"
```

It's not throwing an error because the second one still produces a valid query, it's just looking for records where special is a string with the actual t-r-u-e characters in it.

Comment: ok I changed `"inventories.special = ?", "true"` to `"inventories.special = ?", true` but now it does not show me any results? Let me have a look in schema file quick

Comment: it looks like the column is in fact boolean, or shown in mysql as tinyint, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, since your special field is a boolean, use true/false. Assuming that you do have records where special is true and you're not seeing any results, then it has something to do with another part of your query.